# How to create a method that performs division on 2 double numbers then returns an integer?

Tags: java

I'm doing some training exercises, but I just can't seem to understand a particular assignment: "Write a method that imitates the Java integer division `/` for `double`s and returns an `int` type value."

How do you imitate a division? I had this, but that doesn't seem to qualify for an answer:

```
    int input = intValue(double_input);
    int solution = input / input;
    return solution;
```

Comment: Still unclear to me---what does imitating do here? Are you dividing two doubles and then converting the result into an int?

Comment: `int` is the variable type, you cannot make a calculations with it.  You need to use the actual variable (i.e. `input` for the calculations)

Comment: By "imitate the Java integer division" I think the question is asking for rounding towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can 'imitate' division is to do subtraction until you have a value that the subtraction would result in a negative. you then know that the integer value ( equivalent to the modulo (//) operator result is the count of number of subtractions you did.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(divisionFunction(21, 6));
    }

    public static int divisionFunction(double dividend, double divisor) {
        int quotient;
        if (divisor == 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument 'divisor' is 0");
        } else {
            return quotient = (int) (dividend / divisor);
        }
    }
}
```